# Using broccoliJS with a currently modular backbone app that uses requireJS, and I want to drop requireJS altogether

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, amd, ecmascript-6, broccolijs

I have been scouring the internet to figure this out, and i'm here as a last resort. I have a backbone application that was started using requireJS, as many do. However, I have recently been introduced to broccoliJS to wrap up all my backbone views/models/collections.

One problem that I forsee is that my app is modular, the models have their own directories, so do views, etc - and it's all well and good if broccoli concats and minifies my js, but i'm going to spend a ton of time specifying which files go in which order in my Brocfile so I don't end up with a completely broken app.

There has to be a better way? Like I said in the title, i'm currently using requireJS but I've *heard* that I can use es6 features to modularize and it works incredible with broccoliJS, and if there is a way to do this, I'd like to drop requireJS altogether.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broccoli and Require aren't mutually exclusive. You should use Broccoli to concat and minify your code and continue using Require to ensure dependencies are loaded properly. You could switch to another AMD-type solution, but I think Require should work for you.

If you want to use ES6, then incorporate [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) into your Broccoli pipeline. It transpiles your ES6 modules into AMD modules.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll stick with require and use the broccoli-require plugin. Thanks again!